# How to send e-mail when someone clicks on tel link without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, tel

I need a more precise solution to track phone calls from different pages then Google Analytics. I am thinking of implementing a solution to send an email every time a visitor clicks on a "tel:" link, but without reloading the page.

Is that possible?

Comment: if you want to do anthing with out reloading the page you need to use something client based not server based such as a JS ajax call

Comment: If you set an `onclick` handler for all `a[href^=tel:]` elements which fires off a synchronous (not `async`) XHR request to notify your tracking web-service. Of course your users will hate you (synchronous requests break UX) and the browser might even disregard your handler if it takes too long.

Comment: I'd guess you'd have to use Javascript to handle a click event on the link, send an ajax request with the data (and then PHP would send an email), and then Javascript would re-trigger the real click event on the link. That might work. But what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Why not just store the clicks in a database instead of emailing them? Just remember, if the server/service is in a European country, make sure you adhere to GDPR.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger an action based on an event, you need to use JS/jQuery to do it.

In this case, your requirement is, send an email when the user clicks on the item.

To do this, you can attach an event listener to the element like this
(example uses jQuery)

```
$('#element-id').on('click', handler);
```

You can define the handler as follows

```
function handler() {
  // AJAX request to the send-email end-point at the server
  // do any other action you'd want to do for this click event
}
```

Comment: "`//send an email`" ..from Javascript? Really?

Comment: @ADyson what I meant is, write the email handler method. Not to send an email directly. will edit it :)

Comment: I think it would be better to make clear that the sending of the email has to be done from the server, which then implies an ajax request.

Comment: That's much better. Also for anyone reading, the specific syntax shown here requires jQuery. The same thing can be done using native JS but with different syntax.